# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, synchronize

I've seen a couple of questions about this, but I don't think these answer my problem.

In my method I have... within an if statement, which I use to set a default value upon first launch of my app.

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:@"1" forKey:kNSUAccountSelection];
[myDefaults synchronize];
```

Further down I do the same thing with another key.

Then I run this...

```
NSString *account_name = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:[accountArray 
   indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]]] objectForKey:@"Account_Name"];
```

Which results in an error.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'**

So I tried... directly before that line...

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *str = [myDefaults2 stringForKey:kNSUAccountSelection];
```

And str returns nil.

In my constants.h file I have...

```
#define kNSUAccountSelection @"accountselection"
```

Yes, accountArray is populated from my database and has values.

I don't understand why I'm getting nil and what I have to do fix this ?
From what I've read this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest breaking your 1-liner down a bit.

```
NSString *account_name = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:[accountArray 
   indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]]] objectForKey:@"Account_Name"];
```

Specifically

```
[accountArray 
       indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
       objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]]
```

is causing your error.

the indexOfObject is returning NSNotFound

```
NSNotFound 2147483647
```

EDIT

Your comment confuses me.  Let's call

```
int index = [accountArray 
           indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
           objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]];
```

The 1-liner I referenced is now

```
NSString *account_name = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Account_Name"];
```

Your comment references

```
int num = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:[accountArray indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]]] intValue];
```

becomes

```
int num = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue];
```

What is supposed to be inside of accountArray? dictionaries, strings or numbers?  I know you can mix and match whatever objects you want inside the array, but what are you expecting

```
[accountArray objectAtIndex:index]
```

to be?

Comment: `int num = [[accountArray objectAtIndex:[accountArray indexOfObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection]]] intValue];` returns 19716712

Comment: I responded with an edit because it will be easier to read there.  Just trying to help you get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "if" statement that you're running is happening at all?
the error responds to your array so maybe tell us what's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
NSString *str = [myDefaults2 stringForKey:kNSUAccountSelection];
```

to this:

```
NSString *str = [myDefaults2 objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection];
```

Also, hard code a @"1" in your objectForKey:@"Account_Name" statement to make sure it should return as expected.

Comment: What does this give you:  NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[myDefaults setObject:@"1" forKey:kNSUAccountSelection];
[myDefaults synchronize];  NSString *str = [myDefaults objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection];

Comment: Are you setting the kNSUAccountSelection userdefaults somewhere else in the code?  Maybe overwriting it with null?

Comment: Since you know now that this statement:NSString *str = [myDefaults objectForKey:kNSUAccountSelection];  returns the correct string value right after you set it... I would put this statement every where in your code. Sprinkle it everywhere and find out exactly when it returns nil by either NSLog or debugging.